# Как выбрать все теги “<li>”?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, lxml

имею такую структура сайта:

```html
<div class="wrapper">   
   <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.php">Новости</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacts.php">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a href="company.php">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="map.php">Как добраться</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

И такой код в python

```py
with open("project.html", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    src = file.read()

 soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
 wrapper = soup.find_all("div", class_="wrapper")

 for item in wrapper:
    head = item.find("div", class_="menu").find("li")
    print(head)

get_data("http://old.code.mu/exercises/advanced/php/parsing/poetapnyj-parsing-i-metod-pauka/1/index.php")
```

как сделать так, чтобы он выводил все теги `li`, `find_all` не подходит.

Comment: почему `find_all` не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="menu"><ul><li><a href="index.php" class="active">Главная</a></li><li><a href="news.php">Новости</a></li><li><a href="contacts.php">Контакты</a></li><li><a href="company.php">О компании</a></li><li><a href="map.php">Как добраться</a></li></ul></div></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('li')

for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

выведет список всех `<li>`:

```
<li><a class="active" href="index.php">Главная</a></li>
<li><a href="news.php">Новости</a></li>
<li><a href="contacts.php">Контакты</a></li>
<li><a href="company.php">О компании</a></li>
<li><a href="map.php">Как добраться</a></li>
```

а если так:

```
for r in rows:
    print(f"{r.find('a')['href']:15} {r.find('a').text}")
```

то выведет хвост ссылки и название раздела:

```
index.php       Главная
news.php        Новости
contacts.php    Контакты
company.php     О компании
map.php         Как добраться
```

Comment: Привет, спасибо за ответ, у тебя есть вк, если что буду обращаться к тебе, очень помог